# How can I save my datagridview without any Databases?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created one C# Windows form that have one DataGridView I can add or remove some row from this DatagridView, but now I wonder how can I save my changes, so every time I open my window I can see my added row.

P.S.: I must mentioned that I don't want use any databases, is there any solution?
Is it possible to do that with C# Application settings?

[image]

Comment: you have to save somewhere else, if you are not storing in DB. may be you can store in File (CSV, xml) ???

Comment: some of them (like DACs and Reader are saved in Application setting) and some of them added by user directly (like Location)

Answer (score 5):

Stick the contents into a `DataSet` (boo hiss) and serialize that to either a binary file or as XML.

Let's all laugh at the "cutting edge" label of this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163911.aspx

It won't require a database, just a file.

If you go this route, you could then data bind your grid to this backing `DataSet`, this will make the process of populating the `DataSet` with the contents a lot easier.

Comment: That certainly made me chuckle :-)

Comment: The article was still worth a read for the info on xml vs. binary performance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can save it using C# Application Settings, but you need to do some formatting. Hey buddy, even txtfile can be called as database.

Comment: Can you please tell how can I save it using C# Application Settings

Answer (score 1):

All these answers suggest the following:

Create a new class with methods that take your datagrid as a parameter and save it a particular way. One method for saving as CSV, one for XML, etc. Now you can play with with all this w/out breaking your original code during your learning process.

Then you can assess the various methods [empirically](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/empirically+) and decide which is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I can see is to store this data into disk in XML format. It will also help you to read it back at later stage directly into dataset.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer you can save in xml or csv format to store the app settings, and later you can read through it :) .